# C# Logic in listview

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, logic

Good day sir. I'm making a listview that has a two columns which is the (answers) and (errors), under (answers) are the words from listbox that is selected by clicking. And now my logic here is by stepping, the user pick some steps in the listbox and transfers his choices in the listview which is under the (answers), if his steps that hes choosen is wrong, the errors will appear in the listview under the (error) column, this was the output I expect:

Answer              Error
1
2
5                     next of 2 is 3
4
3                     next of 4 is 5

These numbers you've shown under the (answer) is stored in my ms accessdatabase and also under the (error), this is my sample codes, I hope you understand:

```
        OleDbDataReader reader = Com.ExecuteReader();
        object[] obj = new object[256];



        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.GetValues(obj);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from search", con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
            {
               if (lvAttendance.Items[0].Text.Contains(obj[2].ToString()))
                {
                    lvAttendance.Items[lvAttendance.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[12].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
```

Can you show me a better codes sir? on doing my logic system?

Answer (score 0):

It must use a Loop on making this logic. Here's my codes. I solved it by myself and I want to share this in here:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < listBox2.Items.Count; x++)
            {
                if (listBox2.Items[x].ToString() == check[x])
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add(x+ " Correct ");
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add(x + " Error ");
                }

```
        }
    }
```